# HTML Live field in Ironspeed

Tags: html, ironspeed

I've been trying to add a live output field to my ironspeed application but I have not been successful, the Ironspeed mobile app reads all the fields but it does not display the live output field. I tried searching in the Ironspeed forums, and I watched a number of their youtube videos, where they show you how to enter HTML in Ironspeed but I have not been successful, here is a snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Output element sample</title>
<body>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>Output element sample</h1>
            <p>Demo showing output element in HTML5</p>
        </header>
        <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="totalamount.value = Math.round( Qty.value * exchangerate.value)">
            I have<input name="Qty" id="Qty" type="number">
            <br />
            Exchange Rate<input name="exchangerate" id="exchangerate" type="number">
            <br />
            Total amount <output name="totalamount" id="totalamount" for="principal period interest"></output>
        </form>
        <footer>
            <h1></h1>
            <p>HTML Goodies</p>
        </footer>
    </article>
</body>
 
</html>
```

I would really appreciate some assistance in the matter.

Comment: "*the Ironspeed mobile app reads all the fields but it does not display the live output field.*" -- The code sample you provided above works as expected in the preview. The problem must be with how you are loading it in mobile apps.

Comment: I agree with you, but how do I add it in properly? That is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: You're unfortunately unlikely to find help with IronSpeed-specific problems, especially considering they've already been **shut down** (https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/09/07/sunk_by_patent_troll_iron_speed_stops_ops/). Personally I would abandon using IronSpeed -- their **own** website isn't even responsive. Instead, I'd recommend looking into Cordova (https://cordova.apache.org/) for HTML / JavaScript app development. It's run by Apache, open-source, and much more supported.